# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type with an int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a List of patients.  One of the properties of the Patient class is PatientId which is an int.  My list is initialized like:

```
List<Patient> = new List<Patient>() { new Patient { PatientId = 1, 
                                                    FirstName = "Jane", 
                                                    LastName = "Doe"}};
```

When I access PatientId in my view with something like:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel(modelItem => modelItem.PatientId) //Error
```

I get an error:
`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: have you tried @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.PatientId)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DisplayForModel` actually uses Display Templates to display your model and is normally called without parameters. If this is what you intended then you will have to make a new DisplayTemplate. For anyone interested, here is a nice tutorial by Phil Haack on Display Templates and `DisplayForModel`: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx.

However, if you just wanted to have a label for that field, then you should just use `DisplayFor`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.PatientId)
```

Comment: OK, When I auto-generated my view, it put everything in except PatientId, so it put in `@Html.DisplayForModel(modelItem=>modelItem.FirstName)`.  I am still confused on why it does not work for int's.

Comment: OK, my bad I am an idiot, I don't know why I was seeing DisplayForModel, it has DisplayFor on everything. Time for new glasses. How is the chess coming along?

Comment: @Xaisoft - Really threw me for a loop there, I could not find out why `DisplayForModel` was autogenerated for ints :P The chess is good.

Answer (score 3):

You've confused between `@Html.DisplayFor()` and `@Html.DisplayModelFor()`. The former takes in a lambda. In your case, you could use `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PatientId)`

Comment: Thanks, I was seeing DisplayForModel, but it was actually DisplayFor.